Manipulating arguments with OPTIND, OPTARG, getopts, and shift correctly
My small POSIX shell scripts do not usually take any arguments, so this is kind of new to me...
The minimal snippet would probably look like this:
# default for hotkey variable on top of script is set
hotkey=Print
...
while getopts ':hk:' option; do

    case "$option" in

        k) # override default hotkey variable with supplied arg.
            hotkey=$OPTARG
            shift 2
        ;;
        h) # self-explanatory I assume, prints usage, and exits script with code 0
            print_usage_and_exit 0
        ;;
        *) # inspects unspecified arguments, prints usage, and exits script with code 1
            dump_args "$@"
            print_usage_and_exit 1
        ;;

    esac

done
...

What remains unclear to me, if in this particular case, there is any use for the notoriety known command:
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

Thanks for any direction

You most likely don't want the shift 2 inside the while loop that parses your command lien arguments!

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 )) removes the arguments that were parsed by getopts. For example, if you do ./yourscript.sh -k x y z, that makes $1 be y instead of -k. If you aren't using $@, $1, etc. after your getopts loop, then you don't need that line for anything.
